# Need help with superlatives and comparisons

Tags: comparisons, superlative-degree

I'm unsure of how to handle the following situation, which deals with superlatives and comparisons in English.

Let's say basketball player Mr. A scored 50 points in a basketball game in 2010, his most ever. Then he scored 47 points in a game in 2015, which was his second highest. Then he scored 47 points in a game in 2020.

Is the following sentence correct:

Mr. A scored 47 points in a game last night, his most since also scoring 47 in 2015.

Or because the numbers match, would it need to be:

Mr. A scored 47 points in a game last night, his most since scoring 50 in 2010.

Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I consider it has passed the dividing line into writing advice. Either suggestion is at best clumsy, potentially misleading. 'Mr A scored 47 points in the match last night, equalling his tally in the 2015 match against St Trinian's. Only with his 50 points in the 2010 match against St Keble's has he done better.'

Comment: I understand your point. Forgive me for taking the answer into writing advice, I could not resist. I did go back to be sure to answer the question as it was clearly stated. If any dividing line was stepped over it was on me.

Answer (score 2):

I would say they are both correct but they do not tell the story as well as they might. There is no need to skip the previous 47 just because it was the same as last night.

*Mr. A scored 47 points in a game last night, his most since also scoring 47 in 2015.*

Might be better as

*Mr. A scored 47 points in a game last night, his best since scoring the same in 2015, though he has done better, in 2010 with 50.*

Comment: "Equalling his second highest score which he achieved in 2015" would also work.

Comment: Welcome to ELU and for sending in a question.  As I read it, you seem unsure not about the correct use of superlatives or comparatives but about which of two possible different comparisons  is more accurate?/revealing?.  Whichever of year  2015 or 2010 you use, the comparison looks pointless (unless you are criticising a lack of improvement).  If both 47 and 50 are exceptionally high for one player, then stick with 2015.  But this is about policy not about the use of comparatives or superlatives.